# how to send string to python file and display it using terminal

Tags: python

I want to know how can I get the `string` from `terminal` or `command prompt` and make lower case that string and display it on `terminal` or `command prompt`
I used this code but it's not working

```
// in main.py cmd or terminal

import sys
tdf = sys.argv[1]
print(tdf)
```

and in `terminal`

```
// in cmd or terminal

PS E:\Python\Project\At> python .\main.py "Hi"
```

when I used this in my terminal I got this ***error***

> File "C:\Users\miladm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1256.py", line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 13: character maps to

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing this error, could you give some more info about your python version, operating system, and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
import sys

print ("Data from terminal :",sys.argv)
```

while running the script use:

```
D:\python>python cmdline.py "hello"
```

Output:

```
Data from terminal : ['cmdline.py', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 0):

run with
`python filename.py "arguments"`

instead of

```
tdf = sys.argv[1]
```

Use,

```
tdf = sys.argv[-1]
```

because it will get the last argument on the command line. If no arguments are passed, it will be the script name itself, as sys.argv[0] is the name of the running program. in your case if there is no arguments passed it will create an error

```
import sys
tdf = sys.argv[-1]
print(tdf)
```